# 'if' statements within a 'plot' command in gnuplot

Tags: plot, logic, gnuplot

I am writing a gnuplot (5.2) script and I would like to only plot certain functions or data files if a flag is set. An example of this that works with gnuplot is:

```
if(flag==0){plot sin(x)}

if(flag==1){plot sin(x), cos(x)}
```

so that depending on the value of 'flag' I can make slightly different plots. However, doing it the above way means repeating the plot command for every setting for the flag and this quickly becomes laborious if I have multiple settings for my flag. Is there a way to use the 'if' statement inside a plot command? For example, something like:

```
plot sin(x), if(flag==1){cos(x)}
```

so that I can do everything with only one use of 'plot'.

Comment: What's the point to use plot once? You want the program to be short?

Comment: The actual script I am writing is considerably more complicated than the short example I have given and I don't want to have to repeat the plot command for each different flag.

Comment: The only solution I see is to define a function which decides to plot what based on flag value. This function can minimizes number of times that you use plot in your large code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an empty plot window

```
plot "-" ps 0 notitle
0 0
e
```

(or sth similar) and then do your original scheme, but with "replot"

```
if(flagsin==1){replot sin(x)}
if(flagcos==1){replot cos(x)}
```

Comment: Okay, great, this seems to work for my purposes. Note than when making the initial empty plot you could just use 'plot NaN' as long as you have specified a yrange.

Comment: I guess the disadvantage of your solution is that 'replot' can be annoying to use within multiplot and also that for output vector graphics files I think replot can end up making multiple copies of the same line on top of one another.

Comment: @Mead "multiplot" yes. That can't be helped. But your latter point is definitely no true. "replot" always clears the canvas of everything before redoing the previous plots.

Comment: Or let's say it creates a new, empty plane with a white background that includes previous multiplot output) in the far.

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas:

The first idea uses the ternary operator:

```
unset key
a = 1
plot sin(x), (a == 1 ? cos(x) : NaN)
```

Depending on your needs, key handling gets difficult.

The second idea builds the plot command depending on some flags:

```
# initial plot command which plots nothing, additional functions 
# can be appended with a comma
plot_command = "plot NaN notitle"

sin_flag = 1
cos_flag = 1

if (sin_flag == 1) {
   plot_command = plot_command.", sin(x)"
}  

if (cos_flag == 1) {
   plot_command = plot_command.", cos(x)"
}  

# print the final plot command (just for a check)
print plot_command

# execute the plot command
eval plot_command
```